# Сортировка столбцов QTableWidget PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyqt6

В оригинальном файле с интерфейсом есть `QTableWidget` который в котором рисуется таблица куда выводятся данные из базы:

```
self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(parent=self.frame_7)
sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.table_widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
self.table_widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.table_widget.setObjectName("table_widget")
self.table_widget.setColumnCount(0)
self.table_widget.setRowCount(0)
self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.table_widget)
```

Уже в самой программе определяем колонки:

```
    self.ui.table_widget.setColumnCount(2)
    self.ui.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Info", "Datetime"])
```

Далее в колонке *"Datetime"* подгружаются данные формата *yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss* (дата) , и при сортировке по ней, он это делает, как я подчерпнул  из других источников, по лингвистическому признакам, тк считает данные как str. Это собственно делать не надо, нужны были сортировки даты.

Для применения сортировки был создан отдельный класс для модели сортировки:

```
class DateTimeSortProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        left_date = QDateTime.fromString(self.sourceModel().data(left), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        right_date = QDateTime.fromString(self.sourceModel().data(right), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        return left_date < right_date
```

И я попытался установить данный класс через `setModel` установить его, но оказалось , что для `QTableWidget` данный метод является приватным. и не работает на прямую.

В базу данные заносятся вот так:

```
reminder_datetime = QDateTime.fromString(record['datetime'], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Тогда попробовал свою таблицу перевести в копию класса `QTableView`, там сортировка включается работает.

```
    # изменение модели сортировки для таблицы напоминаний
    self.proxy_model = DateTimeSortProxyModel()
    self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.ui.table_widget.model())

    self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    self.view.setMinimumSize(self.ui.table_widget.size())
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.table_widget)
    layout.addWidget(self.view)
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.view.setModel(self.proxy_model)
    self.view.setParent(self.ui.table_widget)
    self.view.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.view.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.SortOrder.AscendingOrder)
```

Но после этого у меня престают работать функции с `removeRow` , тк ,потом я посмотрев документацию, `QTableView` просто не обладает ими.

Собственно вопрос как установить модель сортировки для `QTableWidget` и не потерять часть функционала?

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решался куда проще чем я заморочился.

Все так же для установки модели используем переход в `QTableView`

## изменение модели сортировки для таблицы напоминаний

```
self.proxy_model = DateTimeSortProxyModel()
self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.ui.table_widget.model())

self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
self.view.setMinimumSize(self.ui.table_widget.size())
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.table_widget)
layout.addWidget(self.view)
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self.view.setModel(self.proxy_model)
self.view.setParent(self.ui.table_widget)
self.view.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.view.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.SortOrder.AscendingOrder)
```

Далее изначально мы обращались к объекту `QTableWidget`, выбирали строку и удаляли ее. Но тк теперь передо мной был `QTableView` , `removeRow` применить было нельзя Закомментированные строки, это первоначальный код функции по удалению строк из базы.

Суть решения - выбираем строку вновь обрисованном объекте `QTableView`, а удаляем в QTableWidget.

```
def delete_selected_row_rem(self):
    # selected_row = self.view.currentIndex()
    # if selected_row >= 0:
    #     self.ui.table_widget.removeRow(selected_row)
    #     self.save_records_rem()
    selected_index = self.view.currentIndex()
    if selected_index.isValid():
        selected_row = selected_index.row()
        self.ui.table_widget.removeRow(selected_row)
        self.save_records_rem()
```